# LDAP vs DNS performance

Tags: dns, ldap

I am a newbie about DNS and LDAP, I have installed both of them to test how it works. However, I just want to compare the difference between them about performance or overhead (network latency, network bandwidth, or overall performance). Is there any benchmark tool or source code to test the difference?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with these tests? Because DNS has a very specific purpose (resolving Domain Names) whereas LDAP is a generic protocol to query Directory-Servers (and can be used as backend for DNS). So depending on your use case and setup the results can vary enormously. In addition to that network latency and bandwidth – at least to my understanding – is depending on a completely different layer of the network stack than DNS and LDAP, so what exactly do you want to find out?

Comment: Thank for your answer @heiglandreas. I intend to use DNS and LDAP to deploy a Naming mechanism in my network and I will want to compare the difference between them (ex: looking up and retrieving the name of the object in-network, or the number of query per second).